# Flash Embedded in Java Desktop App?

Tags: java, flash

I am building a Java app and I want to be able to embed a flash player. Is this possible? Not just a flash video file, but I want to embed an entire player, like we see on the web. Is this possible? If so, how is it done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but you have to use external libraries.
Like [this one](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t105291.html) which lets you have a Flash Player.

Comment: Could I get some help setting this up? I dropped the DJNativeSwing.jar in my project and added it as a jar in properties. The initialize method worked fine but `JFlashPlayer player = new JFlashPLayer();` give me and error and only offers to create that class :(

Comment: I don't think you loaded the right `JFlashPlayer` class. Be sure the class import is : `chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JFlashPlayer`. Then, your `JFlashPlayer` object should allow you to use the `load` method.

Comment: The issue is, it says it can't resolve that! Here is an issue of my configuration: [link] (http://i1084.photobucket.com/albums/j404/ryebread761/ScreenShot2012-08-12at31332PM.png) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When putting your mouse cursor on the `chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JFlashPlayer` line (which should be red underlined if the class is not found), Eclipse should shows you the `fix import ...` option. Click on it. Be sure that the DJNativeSwing is included in the classpath and restart Eclipse if necessary.

Comment: All I get is `fix project setup` and in there the jar is present. Have cleane and restarted, what could be wrong :/?

Comment: Try and open the jar file and find the JFlashPlayer class. If you can't find it, then you have the bad library. So, you'll have to download the latest stable release.